# Unseting the decimal point after a cout.setf(ios::showpoint); instruction

Tags: visual-c++

After I have done a cout.setf(ios::showpoint); instruction, I want to go back the way it was before.

Comment: `cout.setf(0, ios::showpoint);`

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me.